# Oracle "alter session set EDITION.." doesn't seems to work using option sessionInitStatement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to select from a view which is visible when activating Oracle edition feature.

```
alter session set EDITION=MYEDITION

view1
view1_edition1 => this view is only visible after the alter session statement above which is Oracle edition feature.
```

In TOAD all works fine. I fire alter session statement above and I can successfully select from that view.

I am trying to achieve this in Spark but it doesn't work. selecting from view1_edition1 return object doesnt exists.

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_server:1520/SERVICE") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "(select name from schema1.view1_edition1)") \
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("sessionInitStatement","""alter session set EDITION=MYEDITION""") \
    .load()
```

Just to prove that edition is active I fire the following select above in spark.read and it returns correct edition as active

```
  (
WITH a AS (SELECT name FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1)
     ,b AS (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_EDITION_NAME') AS 
     edition FROM DUAL)
SELECT name,edition
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of alter session, try setting the edition name using Java properties before getting a connection from the Oracle JDBC datasource

e.g., 
p.put("oracle.jdbc.editionName", "MyEdition");
...
ods.setConnectionProperties(p);

Comment: Thanks! It did the job.